# CCSprite not responding to Collision

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder, cocos2d-iphone-3

I am a newbie to Spritebuilder and trying to make MARIO Game prototype. What i am doing is I am having 2 sprites, one sprite has fast walking character and other has normally walking character. I am changing the sprite through a button. When i click on the button the normally walking sprite is replaced by fast walking sprite and again clicking back on that button make the normal sprite appear.

Problem :

1. For the very first time when the game starts, collision is detected between ground and character on jumping. But as soon as i change the sprite to fast walking character, no collision is detected on jumping. When i again switch back to normal walking character, then also no collision is detected on jumping.
2. When i make the sprite jump and it starts falling down, to ground some sort of activity (i would prefer saying bouncing) is observed which i also can't say whether it is bouncing back or not. I dont know why it is coming and how to rectify it. I searched stack overflow and some forums. What i found was to use

CCPhysicsBody.iterations

But i dont know how to use it. 
For more detailed explanation you can see the video at this link to undersatnd the full problem. https://www.dropbox.com/s/0fz3qehie76r60k/Game.mp4?dl=0

Please help. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Edit : Here is the code where i am changing the sprites:

```
-(void)setCharacterAnimationFast
{
    if (_turboButton.selected)
    {
        //changing button state;
        _turboButton.selected=NO;

        //changing value of background speed from screen;
        speeedParameter = 50.0;
        speedParameterOfBackgroundObjects=10.0;

        //loading new chracter
        _character =(RightCharacter*)[CCBReader load:@"RightCharacter"];

        //position the laser at helicopter origin
        CGPoint _characterPosition = _fastCharacter.position;

        //transform the world position to the node space to which the laser will be added (_physicsNode)
        _character.position = [_physicsNode convertToNodeSpace:_characterPosition];

        //defining zorder for moving it to background
        _character.zOrder= _fastCharacter.zOrder;

        // add the laser to the physicsNode of this scene (because it has physics enabled)
        [_physicsNode addChild:_character];

        //removing the existing character
        [_fastCharacter removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];



        CCLOG(@"ground : %@", _ground);
        CCLOG(@"ground : %@", _ground.physicsBody);
        CCLOG(@"ground : %@", _ground.physicsNode);



        _ground.physicsBody.collisionMask=@[@"character"];
        _character.physicsBody.collisionMask=@[@"ground"];
        _ground.physicsBody.collisionType=@"ground";
        _ground.physicsBody.elasticity=0;
        _character.physicsBody.collisionType=@"character";
        _character.physicsBody.elasticity=0;
        _physicsNode.iterations=1000;

        _fastCharacter=nil;
    }
    else
    {
        //changing button state
        _turboButton.selected=YES;

        //changing value of background speed from screen;
        speeedParameter = 80.0;
        speedParameterOfBackgroundObjects= 20.0;

        //loading new fast character
        _fastCharacter =(RightCharacterFast*)[CCBReader load:@"RightCharacterFast"];

        //position the laser at helicopter origin
        CGPoint _fastCharacterPosition = _character.position;

        //transform the world position to the node space to which the laser will be added (_physicsNode)
        _fastCharacter.position = [_physicsNode convertToNodeSpace:_fastCharacterPosition];

        //defining zorder for moving it to background
        _fastCharacter.zOrder= _character.zOrder;

        // add the laser to the physicsNode of this scene (because it has physics enabled)
        [_physicsNode addChild:_fastCharacter];

        //removing the existing character
        [_character removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];



        CCLOG(@"ground : %@", _ground);
        CCLOG(@"ground : %@", _ground.physicsBody);
        CCLOG(@"ground : %@", _ground.physicsNode);


        _ground.physicsBody.collisionMask=@[@"fastCharacter"];
        _fastCharacter.physicsBody.collisionMask=@[@"ground"];
        _ground.physicsBody.elasticity=0;
        _ground.physicsBody.collisionType=@"ground";
        _fastCharacter.physicsBody.collisionType=@"fastCharacter";
        _fastCharacter.physicsBody.elasticity=0;
        _physicsNode.iterations=1000;

        _character=nil;
    }
}
```

And here is the link to the video of debug draw: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vt557ngpyj6z9g3/DebugDraw.mp4?dl=0

Comment: Please post the code related to the problems. Also you may want to record that video but with physics debug drawing enabled to better see what the collision shapes are and why they are overlapping when the player hits the ground.

Answer (score -1):

Use the same proxy body node for collisions, its very efficient using less intensive nodes for collision:

```
characterNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:sprite.size.width/2];
fastWalkingCharacterNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:sprite.size.width/2];
```